# BufferedImage always coming null from ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, swing, sockets, udp, jpanel

I am working on an application which send the screen shots of client to a server via UDP socket.

As the maximum size that can be transferred through UDP socket is 64KB, I am splitting the byte array before transmitting. The servier will combine those byte arrays give the full byte array.

Now I am converting byte array to ByteArrayInputStream and then to BufferedImage 
and finally display it in a JPanel.

But BufferedImage is always null.

Client Code:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

class UDPClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        DatagramPacket dp;
        while (true)
        {


            BufferedImage img = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", baos);
            baos.flush();
            byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();
            System.out.println(buffer);
            byte[][] dest=splitBytes(buffer, buffer.length / 10);
            int len=0;
            if (buffer.length%10==0)
                len=10;
            else
                len=11;
            byte[] temp=new byte[]{(byte) len};
            dp=new DatagramPacket(temp,temp.length,ip,3000);
            ds.send(dp);
            for (byte[] bytes:dest)
            {
                dp= new DatagramPacket(bytes,bytes.length, ip, 3000);
                ds.send(dp);

            }
        }
    }
    public static byte[][] splitBytes(final byte[] data, final int chunkSize)
    {
        final int length = data.length;
        final byte[][] dest = new byte[(length + chunkSize - 1)/chunkSize][];
        int destIndex = 0;
        int stopIndex = 0;

        for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex + chunkSize <= length; startIndex += chunkSize)
        {
            stopIndex += chunkSize;
            dest[destIndex++] = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, startIndex, stopIndex);
        }

        if (stopIndex < length)
            dest[destIndex] = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, stopIndex, length);

        return dest;
    }
}
```

Server Code:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

class UDPServer extends JPanel
{
    static BufferedImage image;
    UDPServer() throws IOException {
        DatagramSocket ds = null;
        try {
            ds = new DatagramSocket(3000);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket dp;
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("hello");
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setSize((int)dim.getWidth(),(int)dim.getHeight());
        frame.setContentPane(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        while (true)
        {
            dp= new DatagramPacket(buf, 1024);
            try {
                ds.receive(dp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            int len=(int)dp.getData()[0];
            List<byte[]> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i=1;i<=len;i++)
            {
                blocks.add(dp.getData());
            }
            byte[] imageData=concatenateByteArrays(blocks);
            InputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
            image=ImageIO.read(bais);
            System.out.println(image);

            this.repaint();


        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        new UDPServer();
        //ds.close();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
    }
    public static byte[] concatenateByteArrays(List<byte[]> blocks) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (byte[] b : blocks) {
            os.write(b, 0, b.length);
        }
        return os.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Tried using a debugger resp. trace statements? Are you sure you are putting non-zero on the wire? Are you sure non-zero values arrive at the server? There are **many** places where things can go wrong. You shouldnt expect us to do that debugging **work** for you.

Comment: And for the record: don't do so many things within so few methods. Especially your constructors should do **all** these things.

Comment: yes i have debugged. Non zeros are coming from client to server.Please help. I got struck.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong ... my hint: replace the "reading from socket" within your server with "reading from file" - just to see if that simpler thing works.

Comment: yes it is working.i am able to take an image file convert to buffered image and diaplay it

Comment: Funny thing. Then you probably want to compare all the essentials: like numbers of bytes transferred, maybe even dump parts of the array (first and last x bytes) ...

Comment: In any case: I think your split code is *hard to read*. I had a look three times, and I am not sure if it is really correct. Meaning: a first reasonable thing would be to write code that expresses more clearly what it is doing. You know, bugs hide in code that is hard to understand.

Comment: how should i send you the code. how to contact you

Comment: Sorry, but this is not "we debug your code for free" community. I gave you some starting point, and you have to work from there. I occasionally do "counseling" here, but from my side, this is also a cost/benefit thing. It costs my time; and no benefit at all ... as you dont even have the 15 reps required to upvote content. But maybe you are lucky and I feel tempted to put together something to get you going later on

Comment: My hint: dont try to solve the whole problem in **one** shot. Instead, slice it. And use **unit tests** to test these parts one by one. For example: write a whole class that takes a large byte array an that returns the "sliced" version. Then ensure that you receive the expected results there. And that when you pull together a "sliced" array you end up with **exactly** the bytes you had initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite a lot of errors in your code, but the main reason you don't receive data on server side is because you don't recall the `ds.receive(dp)` method in the receive loop.

There are also algorithm flaws in your program. Look at the solution I propose for something that works (I checked the code on my computer and the screenshot is transferred succesfully).

A big error is maybe that you know the UDP packet size limit and don't need to depend on the sent image size on the image size (`buffer.length / 10`). Instead use 1024 as the chunk size.

The communication between client and server was not clean either. First you have to send to the server the data size, then the data. On the other side, the server can read the data length then it knows how many packets it should read.

I strongly suggest you not to rely on UDP because you can loose packet and your software will not work. Instead of trying to reimplement some control algorithm, maybe you should use TCP instead.

```
// The UDP Client

DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
DatagramPacket dp;
while (true)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    BufferedImage img = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", baos);
    baos.flush();

    byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();

    // FIRST CHANGE : YOU SHOULD USE THE BUFFER SIZE YOU WANT, LIKE 1024 INSTEAD OF buffer.length
    byte[][] dest=splitBytes(buffer, 1024);
    int len=0;
    if (buffer.length%10==0)
        len=10;
    else
        len=11;

    // SECOND CHANGE : YOU SHOULD SEND THE BUFFER LENGTH SO THAT THE SERVER KNOWS WHAT TO RECEIVE
    byte[] temp= new byte[] {
        (byte)(buffer.length&0xff),
        (byte)(buffer.length>>8&0xff),
        (byte)(buffer.length>>16&0xff),
        (byte)(buffer.length>>24&0xff)
    };
    dp=new DatagramPacket(temp,temp.length,ip,3000);
    ds.send(dp);

    System.out.println("sending "+buffer.length+ " bytes to server in " + dest.length+" buffers");

    for (byte[] bytes:dest)
    {
        dp= new DatagramPacket(bytes,bytes.length, ip, 3000);
        ds.send(dp);

        // be careful not to overflow the UDP write buffer
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }
}

// UDP Server

DatagramSocket ds = null;
try {
    ds = new DatagramSocket(3000);
} catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket dp;

JFrame frame=new JFrame("hello");
Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
frame.setSize((int)dim.getWidth(),(int)dim.getHeight());
frame.setContentPane(this);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);

while (true)
{
    // RECEIVE THE IMAGE DATA LENGTH
    dp= new DatagramPacket(buf, 1024);
    try {
        ds.receive(dp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // CHANGE : READ THE DATA LENGTH FROM THE FIRST PACKET
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(dp.getData());
    int len = bais.read()+(bais.read()<<8)+(bais.read()<<16)+(bais.read()<<24);

    List<byte[]> blocks = new ArrayList<>();

    // MAIN REASON YOUR CODE DID NOT WORK : YOU ARE NOT READING AGAIN FROM THE NETWORK
    int received = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (received<len)
    {
        ds.receive(dp);
        received+=dp.getLength();

        // BE CAREFUL NOT ADDING THE WHOLE BUFFER, JUST THE DATA !
        byte[] toAdd = Arrays.copyOf(dp.getData(), dp.getLength());
        blocks.add(toAdd);
    }

    byte[] imageData=concatenateByteArrays(blocks);

    bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
    image= ImageIO.read(bais);
    System.out.println(image);

    this.repaint();
}
```

Comment: sir your code is working fine. But a small problem. It is only displaying the data if the server is executed first and then client but not reverse. i need to make it work either way. please help.

Comment: That's why you should use TCP and not UDP which is not a connected mode protocol.

Comment: In other words what you could do is to use the Socket API.

Comment: If the server is not started, the client won't be able to connect to it, and you can inform the user. With UDP, you cannot know if the server is ready and listening.

Comment: in tcp the client can't send the data unless the server is on.but i want it to happen and it is possible in udp. i want application so that i can execute anything first and if in the process the client is executed first it should send the data. now when server is executed  it should display the data from that time.  please help

Comment: So you can still use TCP. Your client application should retry silently to connect to the server until it is available. Then you send the screenshots to it. Functionally it is the same, just that you rely on a stronger protocol.

Comment: sir can please you provide we with an example or link in which client application should retry silently to connect to the server until it is available.